# How can I change data display in Text Input of ModelChoiceField?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Is there any what to change data display in readonly InputField of ModelChoiceField, but retain the primary key of the object for submitting the form?

```
views.py

class BookingCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    login_url = 'login'
    form_class = BookingForm
    template_name = 'booking_add.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('booking_list')

    def get_initial(self):
        initial = super(BookingCreateView, self).get_initial()
        initial['date'] = datetime.datetime.strptime(self.request.GET.get('date'), '%d-%m-%Y')
        initial['room'] = get_object_or_404(Room, id=self.request.GET.get('room'))
        initial['start'] = get_object_or_404(Period, number=self.request.GET.get('start'))
        return initial

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.user = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

forms.py
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields= ['room', 'date', 'start', 'end']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_args = kwargs.get('initial', None)
        if initial_args:
            super(BookingForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.fields['room'].widget = forms.TextInput()
            self.fields['start'].widget = forms.TextInput()
            self.fields['room'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['date'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['start'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
            self.fields['end'].queryset = Period.objects.get_available_periods(
                initial_args['room'], initial_args['date'], initial_args['start'])


    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(BookingForm, self).clean()
        now = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())

        bookings = Booking.objects.filter(room=cleaned_data['room'], date=cleaned_data['date'])
        booking_start_time = datetime.datetime.combine(cleaned_data['date'], cleaned_data['start'].start, timezone.get_current_timezone())
        booking_end_time = datetime.datetime.combine(cleaned_data['date'], cleaned_data['end'].end, timezone.get_current_timezone())

        for booking in bookings:
            if booking.check_overlap(booking_start_time, booking_end_time):
                raise forms.ValidationError

        if now > datetime.datetime.combine(cleaned_data['date'],
            cleaned_data['start'].end, timezone.get_current_timezone()):
            raise forms.ValidationError

        return cleaned_data

booking_add.html
{% block content %}
    <main>
        <div class="reg-form">
            <form class="form" method="post" action="">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <label for="room">Phòng</label>
                {{ form.room }}
                <label for="date">Ngày</label>
                {{ form.date }}
                <label for="start">Ca bắt đầu</label>
                {{ form.start }}
                <label for="end">Ca kết thúc</label>
                {{ form.end }}
                <button type="submit">Đăng ký</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </main>
{% endblock %}
```

The page is rendered like this:
[image: The form page]

The thing I want is that the input below label 'Phòng' which mean Room, filled with the room object method **str**() not the primary key of Room object and the submitting process still send the primary key.Is there any way to achieve that? Note: the first three fields need to be read only and their data are given via GET request.

Comment: You are changing the widget to `TextInput`, which is why you see the primary key and not the label. Remove this line `self.fields['room'].widget = forms.TextInput()`.

Comment: I know that however I want the field room to be read-only and select widget doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: A select widget by default is "read only" because it does not allow any input. You can limit it to one entry and only show the room's name, or you can convert it to a label. If you change the value of the text field to the name of the room, then you'll have to change the logic in your view to lookup the primary key of the room before you create your Booking model.

Answer (score 0):

I know that however I want the field room to be read-only and select widget doesn't have that attribute.